# Not able to set user_friends permission in facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a facebook app, this app needs to ask for user_friends permission.

But when I give this permission in admin settings section under permission, it doesn't change the permission for my app other then this permission I can set.

Why this specific permission (user_friends) can't be set? Is there anything extra I need to do to set this permission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ask for additional permission like `user_friends` you need to add the permission as `scope` when generating the login URL, instead of adding it under permissions section of the admin settings page of your app.

If you are using `PHP` for your development, then you be to provide the scope as a parameter to the [getLoginUrl ()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/).

```
$params = array(
                          'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
                          'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page' ); 
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Comment: It will be nice if you could accept it as answer So that others with same issue have an answer

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, but I was using the [koala gem](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) for Ruby on Rails.

After trying their [OAuth Playground](http://oauth.twoalex.com/) I found out how to make it work in Rails as well, it's as easy as:

```
oauth     = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(app_id, app_secret, callback_url)
oauth_url = oauth.url_for_oauth_code << "&scope=user_friends"
```

Maybe this might help other Rails/Facebook API beginners.